# How to mock/fake SmtpClient in a UnitTest?

Tags: c#, mstest, microsoft-fakes

I want to use it to fake `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` in a MS-Test UnitTest. Therefor I added a Fakes Assembmly of System.dll. Then I create a `ShimsContext` and a `StubSmtpClient`.

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
   StubSmtpClient client = new StubSmtpClient();               
}
```

But what do I do with it?
The ultimate goal would be to write a Test which expects that the send Method is called with a object of `MailMessage`.

Comment: Write new class, which implements some needed smtpclient methods and use everywhere that interface. Your stub will also implement that interface.

Comment: You mean like I would do it with every other mocking framework as well? I thought this isn't needed with MS Fakes.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx. Read about Shims.

Comment: I did, but there is no such thing as a `System.Fakes.ShimSmtpClient`. The only Shims are for `Guid` and `DateTime`

Comment: Stubs in Microsoft Fakes are just standard stub objects like any other mocking framework. The main advantage is that Fakes comes with visual studio, uses public delegates for everything, and includes Shims. Shims are powerful in that they let you override methods in classes where you can't reach the origin to stub them, but code that requires them is therefore not well designed.

Comment: Additionally, if your test is 'was x called' you should probably rethink something. Your test shouldn't know anything but the input and output of a method. Testing that a method has certain code within it is bad because it will break due to a valid logic change (such as an optimization) that does not change the input and output values.

Comment: Take a look at this Github repo: https://github.com/dfbaskin/SmtpClientFakes

Comment: Another option is an SMTP server running locally. Check out "MailHog" for this exact purpose... now if someone can tell me how to test an SMTP connection which *sometimes* fails so that error handling can be tested..

Answer (score 38):

You can create an interface which will expose functions that will be used from SmtpClient

```
public interface ISmtpClient   
    {
        void Send(MailMessage mailMessage);
    }
```

Then create your Concrete class which will do real job.

```
 public class SmtpClientWrapper : ISmtpClient
    {
        public SmtpClient SmtpClient { get; set; }
        public SmtpClientWrapper(string host, int port)
        {
            SmtpClient = new SmtpClient(host, port);
        }
        public void Send(MailMessage mailMessage)
        {
            SmtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }
```

In your test method now you can mock it and use like;

```
[TestMethod()]
        public void SendTest()
        {
            Mock<ISmtpClient> smtpClient = new Mock<ISmtpClient>();
            SmtpProvider smtpProvider = new SmtpProvider(smtpClient.Object);
            string @from = "from@from.com";
            string to = "to@to.com";
            bool send = smtpProvider.Send(@from, to);
            Assert.IsTrue(send);
        }
```

Comment: Where is your SmtpProvider class coming from? I can't seem to resolve it.

Comment: it appears to be the class being tested

Comment: You are not properly disposing `SmtpClient`

Answer (score 10):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but an alternative aproach:

In the app.config, set up the smtp settings to [deliver the mails as files to a local directory](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/04/send-smtpclient-mails-to-disk/) instead. Then you can load the file and check the contents in your assert section.

You'll have to write a bit more code for the assertion (or preferably create some helper functions) but you won't have to do anything that affects the production code.

Comment: Thanks, this would be a solutions. But I thought with MS Fakes approaches like this aren't needed anymore?

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is to use [nDumbster](https://github.com/EdenRidgway/nDumbster):

`Install-Package nDumbster`

It runs an Smtp server in memory, which you can then verify against. It turns it more into an integration test, but generally those are higher value than unit tests, as you want to test the `SmtpClient` usage is also correct.

Comment: The updated faker for modern .Net is here https://github.com/cmendible/netDumbster

Answer (score 2):

A version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29905984/909882) by [Teoman shipahi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929902/teoman-shipahi) that correctly disposes of the `SmtpClient`.

First make `ISmtpClient` inherit `IDisposable`:

```
public interface ISmtpClient : IDisposable
{
    void Send(MailMessage mailMessage);
}
```

Then implement `IDisposable` in the `SmtpClientWrapper` class:

```
public class SmtpClientWrapper : ISmtpClient
{
    private bool disposed;
    private readonly SmtpClient smtpClient;

    public SmtpClientWrapper(string host, int port)
    {
        smtpClient = new SmtpClient(host, port);
    }

    ~SmtpClientWrapper()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                smtpClient?.Dispose();
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    protected void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (disposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(SmtpClientWrapper));
        }
    }

    public void Send(MailMessage mailMessage)
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

For this version of `SmtpClientWrapper`, I have removed the `SmtpClient` property to avoid the problem of the `SmtpClient` objects not being disposed of when replaced in setter of the `SmtpClient` property.

Comment: `SmtpClient?.Dispose()` probably needs to be `smtpClient?.Dispose()` (lowercase `smtpClient` for the instance variable).

Comment: @gotgenes Thanks. I have amended my answer.

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ why not use using statement?

Comment: @Teomanshipahi My original thought was that Send may be called many times, for example in a loop, and constructing and disposing the `SmtpClient`in the `Send` method would be less efficient.

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ you can use your for loop in using statement.         usage of CheckDisposed method in Send seems like code smell to me.

Comment: `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` should basically never be used. It would be perfectly adequete to simply call `smtpClient.Dispose()` in the wrapping codes `Dispose` method. This version is more prone to memory leaks, etc.

Comment: Consumer should properly dispose the client with the `Using` block.