# Unit testing Smtpclient mock Send method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Is there any way to mock `Send(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message)` method to do nothing when called?
I'm creating SmtpClient using 2 parameters constructor and sending a message like

```
using(var client = new SmtpClient(host, port)){
client.Send(message);
}
```

I don't really need to test it, just want to skip it and move on.
For testing, I'm using XUnit and Moq.

Comment: Tight coupling makes testing this code in isolation difficult. Consider decoupling your code using SOLID principles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock/fake SmtpClient in a UnitTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971364/how-to-mock-fake-smtpclient-in-a-unittest)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to implement any wrapper that implements the same methods.
For example:

```
public interface ISmtpClientWrapper
{
    void Send(MailMessage message);
}

public class SmtpClientWrapper : ISmtpClientWrapper
{
    private readonly SmtpClient _smtpClient;
    public SmtpClientWrapper()
    {
        _smtpClient = new SmtpClient("xxx", 25);
    }

    public void Send(MailMessage message)
    {
        _smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
}
```

And then pass it as parameter in constructor in the main class.

In this case you can use any mock framwork you want.

Comment: SmtpClient should be disposed, hence ISmtpClientWrapper should inherit IDisposable

Comment: Yes. But this is just example.